# Retrieve a column with the list of object_id's that occurs together more than once and a second column with the count of how many times it occurs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

[image]

Note that object_id's 18,10 and 21 are associated to the cart_id 3 once. I wanna know whether the combination occurs again in another cart_id and how many times does that occurs over all the rows existent. I expect two columns as a resultset "combination" and "combination_occurrence_count"

Comment: Just curious, how many different objects (object_id) are in your DB?

Comment: for now just 20 test objects. The app is still in test phase and I am using a seeder to populate tables with Faker data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select group_concat(`app_item`.`object_id`) as `combination`  
from `app_item`
group by `app_item`.`cart_id`
```

[image]

The query return a "combination" resultset as I was looking for:

Since I cannot group again using the "combination" and then make a count of occurrences for each combination and then get the "combination_occurrence_count" it contains, I am now doing this through a method in the application as following

[image]

and now I can display an array as key/pair like "combination" => "occurrence count" as following

[image]

Comment: Are you really going to extract ALL carts items in app and process it there? How many orders are you expecting?

Comment: 5-8k yearly. My clients are small. I think it is worth to display this report despite the fact it consumes a few more miliseconds to get complete. It will not be used every day so, the server capacity (I am still using shared hosting services) will not be compromised.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite complicated task to check all possible combinations as it is [too many of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

However, if you simplify your requirements a bit, you can get something useful.

Lets start with finding all combinations of two items. At the beginning you can try the following query:

```
SELECT
      c1.cart_id   AS cart1_id
    , c1.object_id AS object1_id
    , c2.object_id AS object2_id
    , cx1.cart_id   AS cartX_id
    , cx1.object_id AS objectX1_id
    , cx2.object_id AS objectX2_id
FROM
    cart_item AS c1
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS c2 ON (
            c2.cart_id   = c1.cart_id
        AND c2.object_id > c1.object_id
    )
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS cx1 ON (
            cx1.cart_id   > c1.cart_id
        AND cx1.object_id = c1.object_id
    )
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS cx2 ON (
            cx2.cart_id   = cx1.cart_id
        AND cx2.object_id = c2.object_id
    )
ORDER BY
      c1.cart_id
    , c1.object_id
    , c2.object_id
    , cx1.cart_id
    , cx1.object_id
    , cx2.object_id
```

There are two ideas behind the query:

- Get all possible combinations of two object ids that are exist in
  carts. Carts with only one item will be excluded. The only existing
  combinations would be analyzed (instead of all possible combinations). [c1 & c2]
- Find other carts that have the same object ids combinations [cx1 & cx2]

The results would be something like this:

```
cart1_id    object1_id  object2_id  cartX_id    objectX1_id objectX2_id
3   10  18  30  10  18
3   10  18  31  10  18
3   10  21  30  10  21
3   18  21  30  18  21
30  10  18  31  10  18
```

Then you can group these results to get "the most popular" pairs:

```
SELECT
      cx1.object_id AS object1_id
    , cx2.object_id AS object2_id
    , 1 + COUNT(DISTINCT cx1.cart_id) AS cnt
FROM
    cart_item AS c1
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS c2 ON (
            c2.cart_id   = c1.cart_id
        AND c2.object_id > c1.object_id
    )
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS cx1 ON (
            cx1.cart_id   > c1.cart_id
        AND cx1.object_id = c1.object_id
    )
    INNER JOIN cart_item AS cx2 ON (
            cx2.cart_id   = cx1.cart_id
        AND cx2.object_id = c2.object_id
    )
GROUP BY
      cx1.object_id
    , cx2.object_id
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC
LIMIT
    20
```

Results:

```
object1_id  object2_id  cnt
10  18  3
10  21  2
18  21  2
```

So pair 10 + 18 is the most popular and are exist in 3 carts.
Pairs 10 + 21 and 18 + 21 are in 2 different carts.

You can continue and do something like this for 3-objects combinations.

P.S. I used the following data set (added a few rows to your data to get a bit more interesting results):

```
id  cart_id object_id
10  2   24
9   3   10
3   3   18
19  3   21
12  4   24
1   7   30
5   9   24
2   11  10
20  14  12
14  14  18
8   14  27
13  15  11
7   16  9
18  16  13
15  20  11
6   21  6
4   23  5
17  23  6
16  25  16
11  29  11
23  30  1
21  30  10
22  30  18
24  30  21
25  31  10
26  31  18
```

P.P.S. I have not spent too much time on this so it is possible that I missed something in queries. However, I hope you understand the general idea.

Comment: Yes fifonik, it works fine for pairs. Thanks for the great job and the time spent. You've found that the complexity of it is O^n and the column number will have the length of the longest combination, right? I think I should combine with group_concat and let php do the trick of separating the combinations, since mysql cannot do much with subqueries and grouping with group_concat. I have already tried many ways of joining subqueries and  grouping subsets. To close the subject, I should post an answer to tell you what I have done to solve

Answer (score 1):

The following returns the list of carts with all three objects:

```
select cart_id
from t
where object_id in (18, 10, 21)
group by cart_id
having count(distinct cart_id) = 3;
```

Comment: thanks for replying but 18,10 and 21 is just and example and I expect to show the result count it for every combination in the table. note that there can be also 5,15,31... or 85,100,547,1080,658. the query must work for all the results in the table, not only 18,10 and 21. I expect this list as comma-separated id's as first column and a second column displaying how many times does the combination occur

Comment: @MatteusBarbosa . . . I have no idea what you mean by that comment.    The question seems very clear to me and to be about these three object ids:  "Note that object_id's 18,10 and 21 are associated to the cart_id 3 once. I wanna know whether the combination occurs again in another cart_id and how many times does that occurs over all the rows existent."  If you have a question about every combination in the table, then this is phrased very poorly.

Comment: ok sorry for the example because I tried to be simple on it . look when I said I am expecting it to work "over all the rows existent", which is exactly about "about every combination in the table" as you've just said.

Comment: I need to inform products that have been frequently sold together in many orders. This will generate a good report for the administrator to know which related products perform better on sales.